# PHP Session not holding values

Tags: php

After a good few hours of looking at posts and different forums I finally give up.
I have been learning PHP for the last 24 hours by trying to create a registration and a login page.
Registration seems to be working (I am sure that there are some bugs etc, but as of right now everything seems to be in sql).
As far as my login page, this is where I am having some problems.

### NEW EDIT

Here is my registration.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

//Set error msg to blank
$errorMsg = "";
// Check to see if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
{
include_once 'db_connect.php';
$username = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $_POST['username']);
$password = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $_POST['password']); 
$accounttype = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/','', $_POST['accounttype']);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
//validate email with filter_var
if ((!$username) || (!$password) || (!$accounttype) || (!$email))
    {
    $errorMsg = "Everything needs to be filled out";
    } 
    else {
// if fields are not empty

// check if user name is in use
    $db_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE          username='$username' LIMIT 1");
    $username_check = mysql_num_rows($db_username_check); 
// check if email is in use
    $db_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
    $email_check = mysql_num_rows($db_email_check);

//if username is in use ... ERROR
    if ($username_check > 0)  { 
    $errorMsg = "ERROR: username is already in use";

// if username is ok check if email is in use       
    } else if ($email_check > 0) {
    $errorMsg = "ERROR: email is already in use"; 

    } else {

    session_start();
    $hashedPass = md5($password); 
// Add user info into the database table, claim your fields then values 
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, password, email, accounttype ) 
    VALUES('$username', '$hashedPass', '$email', '$accounttype')") or die (mysql_error());
    // Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
    mkdir("members/$id", 0755); 
    header("location: member_profile.php?id=$id");
    $errorMsg = "Registration Successful";
    exit();}

    }
// if the form has not been submitted
} else { $errorMsg = 'To register please fill out the form'; }
?>
```

---

here's my Login.php

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    // if the form has been submitted
    $errorMsg = "";
    if ($_POST['username']){

            include_once('db_connect.php');
            $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
            $username = strip_tags($username);
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
            $hashedPass = md5($password);


            $sql = "SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE username ='$username' AND password = '$hashedPass'";
            $login_check = mysql_query($sql);
            $count = mysql_num_rows($login_check);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($login_check);
            //var_dump($id, $username, $password);

                if($count==1)
                    {
                        session_start();
                        //$id = $row["id"]; 
                        //                $_SESSION['id'] = $userid; 
                        //                $username = $row['username'];  
                        //                $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
                        //                header("location: member_profile.php?id=$userid"); 
                         echo "User name OK";
                         return true;
        } else {
            echo "Wrong username or password";
            return false;

                    }
                }

    ?>
```

---

Whenever someone registers $id = mysql_insert_id();will pull the ID from the last query and start a $_SESSION['id']. However during a login right after if($count==1) I am completely lost. For some reason the name and the password is checked and does go through but the ID fails.
I did try adding "SELECT id FROM members WHERE id='$id'" but my $id is always undefined.

My member_profile.php is something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$toplinks = "";
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
//If the user IS logged in show this menu
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$toplinks = '
<a href="member_profile.php?id=' .$userid. '"> Profile </a> &bull;
<a href="member_account.php">Account</a> &bull;
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
';

} else {
// If the user IS NOT logged in show this menu
$toplinks = '
<a href="register.php">JOIN</a> &bull;
<a href="login.php">LOGIN</a>
';

}

?>
```

Thank you to everyone for any tips as far as security, structure and coding style. This is day #3 of php for me.

Please excuse any errors.

Comment: [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) does not take any arguments. Why are you passing `'id'`?

Comment: Removed that one, thank you.

Comment: BTW: Your query is prone to SQL-injection attacks. Read this webpage to find out how to protect yourself: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Thanks @TimWolla. I just started with PHP so I am trying to focus on the actual working part. I know that there must be so many security flaws in my code. Will need to read on it and fix it for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` is going inside comments check this --

```
<?php // if the form has been submitted $errorMsg = ""; if
```

edit it --

```
    <?php 
    // if the form has been submitted 
    $errorMsg = ""; 
    if(($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password'])){
```

You are using `mysql` and using `mysqli` in your code too--

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
```

use --

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

Look at your sessions as well as [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263361/php-session-not-holding-values#comment18076839_13263361) mentioned in comments.

```
session_start()
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. My if statement is not inside comments. Must have been an issue when pasting?  Also, PHP manual states that mysql extension is discouraged and instead to use the MySQLi so I was a little bit confused on this one.

Comment: @beacon yes try to use mysqli :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql); to $row = mysql_fetch_array($login_check);  



if($count==1)
                    {

                        $id = $row['id'];
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
                        //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
                        $username = $row['username'];  

                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        header("location: member_profile.php?id=$id");
                        exit();
                        } else {
                        echo "Wrong username or password";
                        return false;
                    }
```

**Also Change your query if you have any id field in table:**

```
$sql = "SELECT id,username,password FROM members WHERE username ='$username' AND password = '$hashedPass'";
```

Comment: Thank you, however there is still an issue with passing the variables.

Comment: I figured out that what I exactly wanted was to retrieve the id generated for an A/I column. In my registration part I declared $id = mysql_insert_id();. That way can I can create a directory for every member by doing mkdir("$id")

Comment: Actually this if statement will redirect to member_profile.php but it will not send the $id so my address bar reads: member_profile.php?id=

Answer (score 0):

First I went over the code. Since this is my day #4 of php, I started changing everything from mysql to mysqli which made a little more sense to me. The code is probably still messy but it does work so far. Thank you

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username' && password = '$hashedPass'");
            $login_check = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            $count = $login_check->num_rows;
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($login_check);
             printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $count);

                if($count==1)
                    {
                        session_start();
                        $id = $row["id"]; 
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
                        $username = $row['username'];  
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
                        header("location: member_profile.php?id=$id"); 
                        echo "User name OK";
                        return true;
```